# Azure and Site to Site VPN

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-vpn

I am planning to enable Azure Cloud Service and On Premise environment connection using Site To Site Connectivity.

Here are specific details that i want to know

```
   1. What would be required from On Premise network team in terms of
enabling the connection?
   2. How do i setup and enable the connection on every deployment build that i do for my Azure cloud service?
   3. What are the ways to troubleshoot if the connection is down?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you'll need a Virtual Network with a VPN to your on premise. After that, you'll add your cloud service to this virtual network. You can do that editting your ServiceConfiguration (.cscfg  file)

```
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="<service-name>" osFamily="<osfamily-number>" osVersion="<os-version>" schemaVersion="<schema-version>">
  <Role …>
         …
  </Role>
  <NetworkConfiguration>  
         …
  </NetworkConfiguration>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

To monitor the traffic you'll just need to watch the Virtual Network dashboard. You'll see data in / out and if connection of the VPN is down.

[image]

More info in here:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2014/03/03/connect-an-on-premises-network-to-azure-via-site-to-site-vpn-and-extend-your-active-directory-onto-an-iaas-vm-dc-in-azure.aspx

Comment: However, when i deploy WebRole/Worker Role, everytime the role restarts, the ip address of the role would change. Now, how would the on premise machine would be able to access the service hosted on WebRole in Azure if the ip address changes. Is there any way?

Comment: Yes, you need to define a ip range in your virtual network. So, every time your role restart, it will pick one ip address from this range.

Comment: Correct. However, for my onpremise machine, i will be configuring an ip e.g. http://10.230.50.60/MyService to call the service on the Azure site to Site VPN machine. Now, if the Role restarts, it will pick up an ip from the range and it might be now http://10.230.50.61/MyService. What would i need to do to OnPremise configuration that it can point to the updated ip address for the Service accessibility.

Comment: Just use the cloud service name. http://something.cloudapp.net and on premise you'll allow the ip address range to connect to your local servers / applications.

Comment: Correct. But what about connectivity from on premise machien to Azure machine. if the ips of azure machine changes, on premise will need update, isn't it? so is there a way i can configure on premise  machine to point to update ip address of azure machine automatically?